# Strang, Intro. to Linear Algebra, Section 2.3, Problem 29: what does it mean that Pascal's matrix is exceptional since all of its multipliers are 1.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 2 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 3 & 3 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

In Strang's *Introduction to Linear Algebra*, 5th Edition Section 2.3 Problem 29 he says that this is Pascal's Matrix and that

> Pascal's triangular matrix is exceptional, all of its multipliers
> $l_{ij}=1$.

Why is this matrix exceptional? Also, it seems the multipliers required in forward elimination for this matrix do not seem to all be 1. Is that a typo or am I missing something?

Comment: Is this in the context of Gaussian elimination? I opened a Numerical analysis book and the only place where the word multiplier appears regarding matrices is in Gaussion elimination. Basically it will be the multiples of the upper rows one needs (in the Guassion algorithm) to create zeroes.

Comment: $l$ is the number of copies of rows you want to subtract from. It's in a number of examples within that chapter

Comment: @GiantRay yes I am aware, but they are not all 1s as he claims when we use elimination on the Pascal matrix.

Comment: @evianpring He uses $-l$ which is confusing. so if you want to subtract, $l$ is positive; and if you are adding $l$ is negative.

Comment: @OliverDíaz This is indeed in Gaussian elimination. It's my bad that I wasn't precise enough in my original post. I know what the term means. I should have asked rather: is there a mistake in his statement? The multipliers are not all 1.

Comment: @evianpring it is. You want to subtract a copy of a row above for each row. So the matrix is 1 in the diagonal, and in the immediate subdiagonal all -1.

Comment: It would be much better if you edit into the body of your question, what it means to say a matrix is *exceptional*, and what it means to say that all its multipliers are one.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You mean that when I make an edit to my own question I should reformulate the actual body of the question rather than adding a separate "Edit" section? The reason I usually don't do that is that sometimes people claim that the question has been altered in a way that invalidates comments that were made before the edit (or something to this effect, it hasn't happened to me in a while).

Comment: I don't want you to alter the question, I want you to define the terms you are using in the question so that I (and others) can understand the question.

Comment: @evianpring: It might be that there is a typo in the textbook. In fact, I think that when the multipliers of the Pascal matrix are properly put in a matrix (lower triangular) you get back $P$. That yours be remarkable.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably just misworded.

The book's claim is true in the following not-really-valid sense: You can fully row-reduce this matrix using $1$ as your multiplier every time, but only if you make very specific and nonstandard choices for the order in which to eliminate entries and also for which row to use for eliminating certain entries. You'd need to do the following steps *in this order*:

1. Subtract row 3 from row 4
2. Subtract row 2 from row 3
3. Subtract row 1 from row 2

At this point you've reached the intermediate point $\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 1 \end{array}\right)$.

4. Subtract row 3 from row 4.
5. Subtract row 2 from row 3.
6. Subtract row 3 from row 4.

...and at this point you've created the identity matrix. This order basically comes down to integrating the subdiagonal entries in the first column **from bottom to top**, then handling the second column from bottom to top, and so on.

That said, if you just generically refer to "the multipliers $l_ij$ that arise during Gaussian elimination for matrix $M$" with no extra information, then absolutely everyone will assume you mean the "standard" order, where we eliminate each column's subdiagonal entries from top to bottom using the diagonal "pivot" entry from that column. So you're correct to be confused by the book's statement.

If you a) understand how it's possible to reduce that particular matrix while only using multipliers of $1$ by choosing your operations in a weird way, but also b) understand that the wording here is imprecise/wrong and Gaussian elimination does have a certain standard ordering, then I think you've gotten all the learning you're going to get from this exercise and I would just not worry about it further.

Comment: It doesn't seem like anything different has been done really in this alternative order of doing the elimination. The final elimination matrix is the same. The same result could have been accomplished by doing it the standard way but instead of, for example, doing something like "subtract row 2 twice from row three" we simply do "subtract row 2 once from row 3" two times. In this latter example, the multiplier is still 2, as far as I can tell, not 1.

Comment: @evianpring The way it's used in this chapter, the "multiplier" is the number you need to multiply (source row) by to make (target entry) become 0. That means it wouldn't be valid to "'subtract row 2 once from row 3' two times" to eliminate a single entry, but we could subtract row 2 from row 3 at two different times (eliminating two different entries). Anyway I would try not to worry about it; there's no deep truth you're missing here, the textbook author just didn't explain their thought process well so this problem is not stated usefully.

Comment: Ok, indeed, this seems to be a recurring theme in this book by Strang. He writes the book as if it were a live lecture with all the imperfections, ambiguities, and imprecisions of live unscripted speech. I sorta hate it, but I will continue since the actual content does seem to be interesting, though harder to understand than it should be given the writing.